# Iterate through a List of Map of Objects and get the length of an item using Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I have a list of Map of Objects. I wanted to find the length of a particular item in a map using Java 8.

```
List<Map<Integer,String>> l = new ArrayList();
Map<Integer,String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(1,"Mark");
m.put(2,"Matthew");
l.add(m);


public int getLength(int param){
//This Method needs to return the length of Matthew/Mark when being passed 1/2
//l.stream()
when getLength(2) is called it should return 7
}
```

Comment: You can't add `Matthew` to your list. Then share an exact example, what param you pass and what value to return

Comment: What did you mean by length?

Comment: are you looking to `l.stream().flatMap(e -> e.values().stream()).filter(param::equals).count();`

Comment: @arzo..You are right,I updated the code.

Comment: @YCF_L No.. when I pass 1 or 2 it should return length of the respective value in the map

Comment: Wait the list can contain duplicate, do you want to count both of them or only the first or what logic you thing?

Comment: you don't need streams here, simply perform `return m.get(param).length()` and what is the use of `l` in your code?

Comment: I delete my answer, I'm waiting the confirmation of the OP, can you clarify this so I can undelete my answer! as I said the List can contain multiple Maps which every one can heve the same key, are you looking to get the first one or what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with some problems in your code, the answer could be as this:

```
public int getLength(String param, List<Map<Integer, String>> l) {
    return l.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.containsKey(param))
            .findFirst()
            .map(e -> e.get(param).length())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Element not found!"));
}
```

---

You have to find the Map which contain the key `param`, I guess you are looking to the first value then you can get the length or throw an exception if the element not found, you can replace `orElseThrow` with `orElse` if you want to return default value.

Comment: how would you conclude `findFiirst` behavior from the question?

Comment: @Naman the OP confirm this [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925510/iterate-through-a-list-of-map-of-objects-and-get-the-length-of-an-item-using-jav#comment113041199_63925510)